# solve this equation $z(z+y)dx+z(z+x)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, self-learning

I need to solve this following equation $$z(z+y)dx+z(z+x)dy=0$$

I get this from above equation

$$\frac{dx}{z(z+x)}+\frac{dy}{z(z+y)}=0$$

After there, I dont know what I need to do.

Comment: The initial equation is exact.

Comment: Can I cancel $z$? Dear @GitGud

Comment: I get the result $$(x+z)(z+y)=c$$ for any constant $c$ right?

Comment: Look into [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation) and consider $F(x,y)=z(x+z)(y+z)$.

Comment: Hmm I cannot cancel $z$ ??? @GitGud

Comment: You can.${{{}}}$

Answer (score 1):

If z is not a function of x or y, then you've already got the equation separated so you can simply integrate.

Paul Safier

Comment: No, $z$ is constant.

Comment: Great, then the solution is just as you state above, (z+x)(z+y)=c.